# Sorting/Accessing Arrays nested in Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, sorting, dictionary, nested, swift5

I have seen how to sort dictionaries nested in dictionaries, but I cannot seem to sort arrays nested in dictionaries.

Here is an example of what I am trying to sort.

```
var dictionary = [3: ["name1", 30, "birthmonth1", 30.50293], 1: ["name2", 35, "birthmonth2", 25.17633], 10: ["name3", 25, "birthmonth3", 32.49927]]
```

I have tried various sorting in Swift 5. However, I am more versed in python and javascript.

On example is:

```
var sortBySecondElement = dictionary.sorted(by: {0[1].value < $1[1].value})
```

How can I get the sort function to work?

Comment: What do you expect the sorted result to be?

Comment: Ah I expected the sorted result to be another dictionary sorted in the key values of 10, 3, and 1 (instead of 3, 1, and 10 like how it is above) since they are being sorted by the second element in the array.

Comment: It seems like each array represents some sort of person? Is the first element the name (of a person), the second element the age (?) of that person, and the third element the birth month of that person? Is there a meaning to each element of the array?

Comment: Yes, each array contains the information of the person and each key is the person's ID number.

Comment: I am trying to sort the information by age, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty solution is:

```
let sortedKVPs = dictionary.sorted(by: { ($0.value[1] as! Int) < ($1.value[1] as! Int) })
```

Note that it is `$0.value[1]`. `$0` is the key value pair, `$0.value` is the array, and `$0.value[1]` is the second element of that array. You also need to guarantee to Swift that the second element of the array is indeed an `Int` with a cast (`as! Int`).

Your array contains both `String`s and `Int`s, so its type gets inferred to be `[Any]`. The compiler can't know the type of each element of this array, because you can put literally anything in it. `$0.value[1]` and `$1.value[1]` may be of different, uncomparable types, which is why you cannot use `<` to directly compare them.

Another thing to note is that the sorted result is not a dictionary. It is an array of key value pairs, because dictionaries aren't ordered, only arrays are.

---

Although the above solution *works*, it is very fragile. Since each array represents a person, you should instead create a `Person` struct to represent a person, rather than an array:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let birthMonth: Int
    let someOtherProperty: Double // I don't know what the fourth element in the array means
}

let dictionary = [
    3: Person(name: "name1", age: 30, birthMonth: 1, someOtherProperty: 30.50293),
    ...
]
```

Now sorting becomes very easy:

```
let sortedKVPs = dictionary.sorted { $0.age < $1.age }
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get four errors: "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to closure result type 'Bool', Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' Insert ';'" and two others including "Expected expression"

Comment: I admit the code is really hard to work with. Honestly, I would prefer using a tuple or nested dictionaries, but the instructions for my assignment tells me to use only one dictionary with the key being the person's id number and use multiple arrays to arrange the rest of the information of the person.

Comment: @DanielJung [I cannot reproduce the errors.](https://repl.it/@Sweeper777/SoupyGlamorousMaintenance#main.swift)

Comment: I guess the dictionary I am using might help. I am trying to sort by the 10th element in the array (the number is a double/float).

Comment: Here is a part of the dictionary I am working with: dictionary = [22: ["Ryan Carpenter", 22, "Forward C R", 200, 33256, "Oviedo, FL, USA", 72, "1/18/1991", "January", "USA", 30.1108829568789], 77: ["Kirby Dach", 77, "Forward C R", 197, 36912, "Fort Saskatchewan, AB, CAN", 76, "1/21/2001", "January", "CAN", 20.1013004791239], 12: ["Alex DeBrincat", 12, "Forward LW R", 165, 35782, "Farmington Hills, MI, USA", 67, "12/18/1997", "December", "USA", 23.1950718685832], 38: ["Brandon Hagel", 38, "Forward LW L", 174, 36034, "Saskatoon, SK, CAN", 71, "8/27/1998", "August", "CAN", 22.5051334702259]]

Comment: If I do a nested dictionary, it becomes easier to retrieve the values so I might end up doing it. [22: ["Player Name": "Ryan Carpenter", "#": 22, "Position": "Forward C R", "Weight": 200, "Birth Date": 33256, "Birthplace": "Oviedo, FL, USA", "Height in In": 72, "Birth Date": "1/18/1991", "Birth Month": "January", "Country of Birth": "USA", "Age in Years": 30.1108829568789]]

Comment: Then you'd use `as! Double` rather than `as! Int`, and `[10]` instead of `[1]`. [Still can't reproduce](https://repl.it/@Sweeper777/SoupyGlamorousMaintenance#main.swift). Did the error occur on the `sorted` call, or the lines after the sorting (which you haven't shown and unrelated to this question)?

Comment: It happens in the sorted code. It specifically highlights the brackets {.

Comment: AH. I realized what the error was. One of the brackets was flip-flopped. It seems to work now!